# OpenGL not showing intermediate colors

Tags: c++, opengl, colors, shader, rgba

I'm importing .obj and .stl files using OpenGL and attempting to color each face. As a proof of concept that I can color the object, I assigned each vertex an integer in the order it was imported (1 for the first vertex, 2 for the second vertex, 3 for the third and etc.) Next, I created a function that maps the index of the vertex to an RGB value. When I drew all of the faces, the faces only had a few different colors - and there were no color transitions. In other words, the colors I saw did not smoothly transition - rather, there were a few defined colors with fairly defined lines in between.
That gave me a hunch that OpenGL might not be displaying the colors how I want them, so I set all of the vertices of all the faces to orange in my `createVertexArray` method - which initializes the `glBufferData`. The output showed the model yellow instead of orange. What could be causing this?

RGB 255,162,0 is orange

createVertexArray:

```
 void createVertexArray(std::vector<triangle> & facet, std::map<vec3d, GLfloat> & vecMagMap, float* vertices, std::vector<GLfloat> mags, GLfloat j_min, GLfloat j_max)
{
     const int NUM_FACETS = facet.size();
     std::cout << "\nNUMFACETS: " << NUM_FACETS << "\n";
     int count = 0;
     hsv temp;
     rgb tempRGB;
     int tempH = 0;
     for (int facet_index = 0; facet_index < NUM_FACETS; facet_index++){
         tempRGB = getColor(vecMagMap[facet[facet_index].point[0]], 0, vecMagMap.size());
         temp = rgb2hsv(tempRGB);
         //if (tempH != temp.h){ std::cout << tempH << "\n"; tempH = temp.h; }
             vertices[count + 0] = facet[facet_index].point[0].x;
             vertices[count + 1] = facet[facet_index].point[0].y;
             vertices[count + 2] = facet[facet_index].point[0].z;
             vertices[count + 3] = facet[facet_index].normal.x;
             vertices[count + 4] = facet[facet_index].normal.y;
             vertices[count + 5] = facet[facet_index].normal.z;
             vertices[count + 6] = 255;
             vertices[count + 7] = 162;
             vertices[count + 8] = 0;
             vertices[count + 9] = 1.0;
             vertices[count + 10] = facet[facet_index].point[1].x;
             vertices[count + 11] = facet[facet_index].point[1].y;
             vertices[count + 12] = facet[facet_index].point[1].z;
             vertices[count + 13] = facet[facet_index].normal.x;
             vertices[count + 14] = facet[facet_index].normal.y;
             vertices[count + 15] = facet[facet_index].normal.z;
             vertices[count + 16] = 255; 
             vertices[count + 17] = 162;
             vertices[count + 18] = 0;
             vertices[count + 19] = 1.0;
             vertices[count + 20] = facet[facet_index].point[2].x;
             vertices[count + 21] = facet[facet_index].point[2].y;
             vertices[count + 22] = facet[facet_index].point[2].z;
             vertices[count + 23] = facet[facet_index].normal.x;
             vertices[count + 24] = facet[facet_index].normal.y;
             vertices[count + 25] = facet[facet_index].normal.z;
             vertices[count + 26] = 255; 
             vertices[count + 27] = 162;
             vertices[count + 28] = 0;
             vertices[count + 29] = 1.0;
             count += 30;
     }
 }
```

part of main where I do the drawing:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &bufferID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,facet.size()*30*sizeof(GLfloat),vertices,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
     glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT,  // options: GL_FRONT, GL_BACK, GL_FRONT_AND_BACK
              GL_FILL);  // options: GL_POINT, GL_LINE, GL_FILL (default)
     glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH); // shading model
     scale = 5.0*scale_0;     // initial scale
     delta = 0.010*scale_0;   // change in scale
     int frame = 0;
     while(running){
         drawGeometry(argv, window, scale, frame,vertices, 3*facet.size(),move_x, move_y, move_z,rotate_x, rotate_y, rotate_z);// render objects in the window
         if(!pause){rotate_x += drot_x;rotate_y += drot_y;rotate_z += drot_z;}
         glfwSwapBuffers(window);// swap front and back buffers
         glfwPollEvents();// poll for and processs events
     }
```

Comment: OpenGL might be clamping those floating-point color values down to the `[0.0-1.0]` range before drawing them.  So RGB(255, 162, 0) -> RGBF(1.0, 1.0, 0.0) == RGB(255, 255, 0), which is yellow.  Edit in a [mcve] that shows `drawGeometry()` and how you're setting up your vertex layout so we can tell for sure.

Comment: genpfault is correct. Because you are using interleaved arrays of float, the colors have to be 0.0 to 1.0 fractions, not bytes. R >= 1.0, G >= 1.0, B = 0 is yellow.

Comment: @genpfault you were right! Making the values doubles and dividing by 255 (to test) solved the issue. Not sure why I thought RGB was drawn based on (255,255,255,1) in OpenGL. Thanks! Should I answer my own question or let you do it?

Comment: @HughFisher Thanks, that solved my issue! Been trying to figure it out for hours.

Comment: @Amadeus, turns out I was using incorrect values in RGB, but thanks for the link - it was quite informative!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenGL is probably clamping those floating-point color values down to the [0.0-1.0] range before drawing them. So RGB(255, 162, 0) -> RGBF(1.0, 1.0, 0.0) == RGB(255, 255, 0), which is yellow.

Use floating-point colors in the [0.0-1.0] range or use an array of `GLubyte` and `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` for the `type` parameter of (I assume) your `glColorPointer()` call.